# How to dynamically size a rectangular path with animated stroke thickness?

Tags: wpf, xaml, rectangles, wpf-animation

I have a `Rectangle` and a `Path` defined by a `RectangleGeometry`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Stroke="Red" Width="{Binding RctWidth}"/>
    <Path Grid.Row="1" Stroke="Red">
        <Path.Data>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,10"/>
        </Path.Data>
        <Path.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="StrokeThickness">
                        <DoubleAnimation RepeatBehavior="Forever" From="1" To="3" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>          
            </EventTrigger>
        </Path.Triggers>
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

The rectangle changes its width dynamically according to the binding.
The rectangular `Path` has an animation applied on its `StrokeThickness`.
I want the rectangular `Path` to exactly match that rectangle in size, but in such a manner that the stroke thickness animation won't affect that (the thicker stroke should make the `Path` actually a little bit bigger than the `Rectangle` - that's the intended behavior).

How can I do that?

Note, that I cannot use the `Stretch="Fill"` property on the `Path`. In that case, the stroke thickness will grow only inside the `Path`s bounds, but I want to keep the default behavior of stroke's growing both in the inner and outer directions.

Furthermore, I cannot change the view model the `Rectangle`'s width is bound to. It's an external component that I'm not allowed to modify.

I could get rid of that `Rectangle` actually. The important thing for me is the `Path` and its dynamically changing width.

Comment: You can bind `Path.Data` to a property in your view model. Each time `RctWidth` changes, you can create a new `RectangleGeometry` and assign to that property.

Comment: @YusufTarıkGünaydın, if life would be so easy... Unfortunately I cannot touch the view model because it's an external component. I'm looking either for a pure XAML way or maybe some attached properties/behaviors/whatsoever.

Comment: Maybe you can add negative margins, canceling the effect of increased thickness...

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing your expected result. Are you trying to re-create something like the `box-sizing` property of CSS? If you can give a visual example of the issue, and the desired result I'm sure we could get it sorted. :)

Comment: If creating a property on the view-model containing `RectangleGeometry` for `Path.Data` that would change with `RctWidth` would solve your problem, then I'm pretty sure you can achieve similar effect by binding directly to `RctWidth` and using a dedicated converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, the effect of stroke thickness growing only to the inside can be canceled by negative margins.

For an animation that changes the thickness from 1 to 3, the margin needs to change from 0 to -1 (compensate for half of the thickness change):

```
<BeginStoryboard>
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness" RepeatBehavior="Forever" From="1" To="3" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" RepeatBehavior="Forever" From="0" To="-1" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
    </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

With this, you can use your solution with `Stretch="Fill"`, whatever it might look like.

Comment: Well, that's it. A simple solution that works with the `Stretch` mode. It's really confusing me why I haven't tried the animated margin...